# Display uploaded files in Django

Tags: django, filefield

I have a dashboard that displays files you uploaded.  But I can't seem to figure out how to iterate through the files.

Here are my models:

```
@python_2_unicode_compatible
class Client(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    company = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.company

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = _("Clients")
        verbose_name = _("Client")
        permissions = (
            ("can_upload", _("Can upload files.")),
            ("can_access_uploads", _("Can access upload dashboard.")),
            ("is_client", _("Is a client.")),
        )

@python_2_unicode_compatible
class ClientUploads(models.Model):

    client = models.OneToOneField(Client)
    #created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def generate_filename(self, filename):
        name = "uploads/%s/%s" % (self.client.company, filename)
        return name

    file_upload = models.FileField(upload_to=generate_filename)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.client.company

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = _("Client Uploads")
        verbose_name = _("Client Upload")
```

Here is my view:

```
@login_required(login_url='/dashboard-login/')
def dashboard(request):
    current_user = request.user
    current_client = request.user.client

    files = ClientUploads.objects.filter(client=current_client).values('file_upload')

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UploadFileForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            new_file = ClientUploads(client=current_client, file_upload = request.FILES['file_upload'])
            new_file.save()

        return HttpResponsePermanentRedirect('/dashboard/')
    else:
        form = UploadFileForm()

    data = {'form': form, 'client': current_client, 'files': files}
    return render_to_response('dashboard.html', data, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

And here is the template:

```
{% load i18n %}

<table class="table">
    <div>
        <p>{{ files }}</p>
    </div>
<tr>
    <th>{% blocktrans %}Filename{% endblocktrans %}</th>
    <th>{% blocktrans %}Size{% endblocktrans %}</th>
    <th>{% blocktrans %}Uploaded At{% endblocktrans %}</th>
</tr>
{% for file in files %}
<tr>
    <th>{{ file.name }}</th>
    <th>{{ file.size }}</th>
    <th>{{ file.url }}</th>
</tr>
{% endfor %}

</table>
```

The test div in the template displays [{'file_upload': u'uploads/Company/archive_addin_log_408hdCy.txt'}]  Which is what I uploaded.  So it's working, but I can't figure out how to iterate through all of the uploaded files.  All I see are a bunch of blank lines under the table headings.

I use `files = ClientUploads.objects.filter(client=current_client).values('file_upload')` to get the files, I've tried a few other ways but can't seem to get it to work.  I tried `files = ClientUploads.objects.filter(client=current_client)` but then I just get a QuerySet object and am not sure how to extract the file names and iterate through.  I really don't understand it.

Any help would be much appreciated as I am very confused.  I just can't seem to get the file object out of the model.  How can I return a list of the objects and then in the template display the file object from the filefield and also display the created_at field.  I need help understanding how to access the different fields within the model.  If I had a list of file objects within that model I could just iterate through that and the created_at field, but I don't see how to do that.

Any suggestions and examples would help a ton.

Thanks

EDIT:

I also want users to be able to download the files, right now if they click the name it displays the file in the browser as I am serving media.  I most likely will disable this.  But I do need to let the user download the files that are displayed.  How can I accomplish this?  I can't find any information regarding how to let a user download a file.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`values()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.values) returns a special class named `ValuesQuerySet` which acts like a list of dictionaries containing the properties you pass into that as key/value pairs.

Given the above information, the following query will give you a list of dictionaries where each of them contains a `FileField` instance for each ClientUploads object:

```
files = ClientUploads.objects.filter(client=current_client).values('file_upload')
```

It may not be easy to iterate over a list of dicts in the template so I would change the above query as follows:

```
files = ClientUploads.objects.filter(client=current_client)
```

and update *for* loop in the template like this:

```
{% for file in files %}
 {% with uploaded_file=file.file_upload %}    
  <tr>
    <th>{{ uploaded_file.name }}</th>
    <th>{{ uploaded_file.size }}</th>
    <th>{{ uploaded_file.url }}</th>
  </tr>
 {% endwith %}
{% endfor %}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: It worked but it only shows the first file, how can I make it show all of them?  Also is there a way to trim the filename so it's just the filename and not /uploads/clientname/filename

Comment: Because `<tr></tr>` must have been inside `for` loop. I updated my answer.

Comment: Didn't make a difference

Comment: Are you sure you have more than one `ClientUploads` object in your database for the current client?

Comment: Yes I have uploaded a few files.  Is there a way to check with the django shell?

Comment: You are clearly wrong. Because you said in your question that `<div>` displays the following: `[{'file_upload': u'uploads/Company/archive_addin_log_408hdCy.txt'}]` which is a list with length `1` which means you have only 1 object for current client. Print `files` in your view and make sure it has more than one item in it.

Comment: Yeah I have a bunch of files in the upload folder that I had uploaded, but now I'm having trouble with the upload all of a sudden so I'm trying to fix it to test it again.  I'm getting a column_id is not unique error.  Any idea how to handle that?  Also oddly if I delete the file that is showing up and delete the model it still asks for the file when I load that template.

Comment: @shenk It seems the problems you are getting now have nothing to do with the question you asked. Please fix those problems first and then make sure this answer works for you.

Comment: I think you actually solved my problem but I can't be sure until I can test it.  Will accept when I do.

Comment: Well I fixed all of my database issues, but I still run into this issue:  When I go to upload a second file, I get the error: `column client_id is not unique`  I'm not sure why.  Otherwise everything is working perfect.  Why would I get that error?  Oddly enough the file actually does get uploaded, but this error appears which I would assume means the database is having trouble recording the upload in the model.

Comment: I think you're getting that error because you have `client = models.OneToOneField(Client)`, which means that there can be only one `ClientUploads` instance per `Client`. Try changing that line to `client = models.ForeignKey(Client)`